# Check if associate model start date is in the next 24 hours in task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm having issues with this task. Essentially I want to send a daily email to users only if they are a premium member (Users who have an expiry date that isn't NULL) AND they have a reminder in the next 24 hours.

Models look like this:

```
class Reminder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope { order('start DESC') }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reminders    
end
```

I've started to work on the task but am having a hard time getting my head around it. Here's where I got to, which throws an error.

```
task :reminder => :environment do
  @users_mailed = User.where(:expiry != 'NULL')
  #expiry is set when someone becomes a premium member

  @users_mailed.each do |user|
     if user.reminder.where("start >= ?", DateTime.now).where("start <= ?", 1.day.from_now)
       ReminderMailer.daily_email(user).deliver
     end
  end
end

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `reminder' for #<User:0x007fad14d06998>
```

The mailer looks something like this and works exactly the way I want if I just pass a user into it.

```
class ReminderMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  add_template_helper(ApplicationHelper)
  default from: "My Site <noreply@mysite.com>"

  def daily_email(user)
    @user            = user
    @user_reminders  = user.reminders.where("start >= ?", DateTime.now).where("start <= ?", 1.day.from_now)
    @timezone        = user.timezone
    @url             = 'mysite.com'
    mail(to: user.email, subject: 'Your reminders for ' + Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
  end 
end
```

How can I make this task work the way I want it to?

Comment: Your error is happening for the reason @FilipBartuzi exposed. But pay attention to the way you compare dates using UTC time (1.day.from_now for example) and local time (DateTime.now). Think about changing DateTime.now for Time.zone.now for UTC.

Comment: Ugg yes re: reminder(s). That was dumb. Thanks, I'll look into the timezone stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 things to make your code right:

1 - I could not make it work.

```
@users_mailed = User.where(:expiry != 'NULL')
```

Use:

```
@users_mailed = User.where.not(:expiry => nil) 
#or simply 
@users_mailed = User.where('expiry is NOT NULL')
```

2 - As exposed by @FilipBartuzi:

```
if user.reminder.where...
```

There should be an 's' in reminders. Typical typo since you call it correctly in the mailer method.

3 - Avoid mixing DateTime.now and Time.now with 1.day.from_now and stuff. You're comparing times with different Time zones. Since it checks reminders for the next 24h, depending on your local timezone you could be checking reminders in an 27 or 23 hours of interval, for example. [This link](http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/) is very good to grasp the concept I'm talking about.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You use helper `has_many :reminders`. That means rails adds method `.reminders` to User model, not `.reminder` which you are using above. Depending on what you want to achieve change all `.reminder` calls for `.reminders` and iterate through them or change `has_many` to `has_one`

Comment: The way the user described, it seems a User really has_many Reminders. Not has_one. So your first suggestion is more accurate. If he changes to has_one, it all falls apart.